# Is there a guarantee that process ids on Windows will not be reused within a certain amount of time

Tags: windows

I have a script which spawns multitple processes and then keeps track of them via their process id, I wouldn't want one to close and then another process to take that pid within the time that I am checking. Is there any guarantee? So far, I have found that no one really knows when they get reused if it is random or not.

Comment: Then you may want something more unique as your 'key'... For instance, you could munge together the processid, the program name, and another piece of persistent data and possibly even hash that string to get a more unique handle

Comment: Yeah using the program name is a way to single it out even more, if something was executed and grabbed the handle that I was keeping track of within a second of it closing, at least checking the name would help things, although not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process ID is a value associated with the process object, and as long as the process object is still around, so too will its process ID. The process object remains as long as the process is still running (the process implicitly retains a reference to itself) or as long as somebody still has a handle to the process object.

If you think about it, this makes sense, because as long as there is still a handle to the process, somebody can call WaitForSingleObject to wait for the process to exit, or they can call GetExitCodeProcess to retrieve the exit code, and that exit code has to be stored somewhere for later retrieval.

When all handles are closed, then the kernel knows that nobody is going to ask whether the process is still running or what its exit code is (because you need a handle to ask those questions). At which point the process object can be destroyed, which in turn destroys the process ID.

What happens if somebody calls OpenProcess on a zombie process? The same thing that happens if they call it on a running process: They get a handle to the process. Why would you want to get a handle to a zombie process? Well, you might not know that it's a zombie yet; you're getting the handle so you can call WaitForSingleObject to see if it has exited yet. Or you might get the handle, knowing that it's a zombie, because you want to call GetExitCodeProcess to see what the exit code was.